# How to repeat the random combination of images using loop and insert them in A4 format correctly?

Tags: image, loops, random, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make this short script work which randomly overlays 3 different images (see the images link below). It would have to loop N times and then assemble them at the end into a single image of (possibly) A4 size. I've tried different combinations several times but I'm confused and can't get the loop to work properly (the images are all identical copies of the first one and paste proceeding on the right) neither fit the images in A4 format. Any help really really appreciated!

Background:

[image: Background]

Orange dot:

[image: Orange dot]

White X (transparent background):

[image: White X]

Wrong result:

[image: Output]

Desired Output (Please note that the orange dot actually prints in a different position each time but I was unable to create the output correctly) :

https://ibb.co/n1XNz9K

Note: I've removed the snippet of A4 code because it was just messing up the script.

```
from PIL import Image
import random

#bckgnd = 200x200
#whiteX = 200x200
#orangedot = 30x30

bckgnd = Image.open('background2.png').convert('RGBA')  # Convert to mode supporting alpha.

orangedot = Image.open('orangedot.png')
orangedot_x, orangedot_y = random.randint(30, 170), random.randint(0, 100)
tmp_img = Image.new('RGBA', bckgnd.size, color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
tmp_img.paste(orangedot, (orangedot_x, orangedot_y))
bckgnd.alpha_composite(tmp_img)

whiteX = Image.open('whiteX.png')
tmp_img = Image.new('RGBA', bckgnd.size, color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
tmp_img.paste(whiteX)  # Assumes it's the same size as background image.
bckgnd.alpha_composite(tmp_img)



bckgnd.save("test.png")
bckgnd.show()


img_to_paste = Image.open('test.png')
width, height = img_to_paste.size

n = 20  # paste image n-times

img = Image.new('RGBA', (width * n, height), color=(0, 0, 0, 0))  # set width, height of new image
img.save('out.png')

for i in range(0, n):
    out = Image.open('out.png')
    out.paste(img_to_paste, (i * width, 0))  # the second argument here is tuple representing upper left corner
    out.save('out.png')

#img.show()
```

Comment: What's actually wrong with the shown "wrong output"? And, what exactly is the desired output? Can you provide a sketch or something similar?

Comment: Hi HansHirse! unfortunately the same identical image is repeated while in reality the script always generates a different image (the orange point behind the white cross is placed at each loop in a different place) .I have placed the for loop in the wrong point and also I cannot generate and assemble the images in a rectangular format type A4 (a similar size would also be fine). The output should be as the last image (desired output) but keeping in mind the differences through the random function.

Comment: How is that random please? It looks like the orange dot and white cross laid out on a regular grid? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Hello Mark, I'm sorry but I'm not able to show You the correct output. The interested line is: orangedot_x, orangedot_y = random.randint(30, 170), random.randint(0, 100) where the orange dot is printed every time in a different place (while the white X remains centered on a black background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the A4 paper size like image, just choose a resolution like `dpi = 300`, and calculate the needed number of tiles in `x` and `y` direction from the actual A4 paper size of `21.0 cm x 29.7 cm`, and the resolution. Limit to whole tiles, i.e. your final image will become a little smaller than actual A4.

Since you now already have the number of tiles in `x` and `y` direction, just set up a nested `for` loop, and access each tile in the final image directly. There, paste the background image, the orange dot image with randomly generated location, and finally the white X image.

That'd be my solution:

```py
from math import floor
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

# Read all images
bckgnd = Image.open('background2.png').convert('RGBA')
orangedot = Image.open('orangedot.png')
whiteX = Image.open('whiteX.png')

# Width and height of each "tile"
w, h = bckgnd.size

# Calculate number of tiles for x and y direction by A4 paper size
# (21 cm x 29.7 cm), and some resolution like dpi = 300
n_tiles = (floor((21.0 / 2.54 * 300) / w), floor((29.7 / 2.54 * 300) / h))

# Prepare final image of sufficient size
final_img = Image.new('RGBA', (n_tiles[0] * w, n_tiles[1] * h), color=(0, 0, 0, 0))

# Iterate all tiles
for i_x in range(n_tiles[0]):
    for i_y in range(n_tiles[1]):

        # Upper left (x, y) coordinates of current tile
        x, y = i_x * w, i_y * h

        # 1st: Paste background to current tile
        final_img.paste(bckgnd, (x, y), mask=bckgnd)

        # 2nd: Randomly generate location of orange dot and paste to current tile
        od_x, od_y = randint(30, 170), randint(0, 100)
        final_img.paste(orangedot, (x + od_x, y + od_y), mask=orangedot)

        # 3rd: Paste white X to current tile
        final_img.paste(whiteX, (x, y), mask=whiteX)

# Save and show final image
final_img.save('final_img.png')
final_img.show()
```

And, that'd be the output:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks so much Hans!! You really solved a problem I was stuck on. Now it all makes a lot more sense! Thanks again!!